# Docker build: No matching distribution found

Tags: docker, pip, dockerfile

I try to build a docker image with pip `RUN pip3 install *package* --index-url=*url* --trusted-host=*url*`. However, it fails with the following error:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement *package* (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for *package*`.

However, after I removed the package and successfully build the image, I could successfully install the package from docker container!

The bash I used to build image is: `sudo docker build --network=host -t adelai:deploy . -f bernard.Dockerfile`.

Comment: You want to install the required libraries for your project?

Comment: My company uses docker environment to control online version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved: I set the environment variable during build (`ARG http_proxy="*url*"`) and unset it (`ENV http_proxy=`) just before the installation.

I am not an expert in docker, but guess the **reason** is that the environment variables are discarded after the build, which cause the environments are different between dockerfile and docker container.

@Matthias Reissner gives a solid guide, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26222636/3293726) absolutely provide a more detailed way to debug problems during docker building.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
docker run --rm -ti python bash
```

Then run your `pip ...` inside this container.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. It is working again. Both the package and base image are created by my company. Is there any clue of what might be the cause please?

Answer (score 0):

I think an extra `\` could also be the reason, for example:

```
RUN apt-get update -y &&  \
   python -m pip install --upgrade pip &&  \
   python -m pip install -U wheel poetry==1.5.0 \ <-- remove this 
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
```

Notice the `\` at the end of the third line. This could result in the following error:

```
12.79 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (from versions: none)
12.80 ERROR: No matching distribution found for AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
```