# How to view image when buildkit is on?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

Say I have a very basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox
RUN something
```

Also, say my local registry is empty.

If I run `docker build`, after build is done, I show be able to view `busybox` image by `docker images`, and inspect the image by `docker inspect busybox`.

But I find that, if I turn on buildkit: `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build`, after build is done, "busybox" will not be returned from `docker images`, thus I cannot inspect it either.

My question is, when buildkit is on, how can I view and inspect images that are pulled during build?

Comment: [Getting docker build to show IDs of intermediate containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65614378/getting-docker-build-to-show-ids-of-intermediate-containers) suggests turning BuildKit off for this use case, FWIW.