# Forked docker image not building

Tags: docker

I am trying to fork [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/randomdude/gcc-cross-x86_64-elf) so that if anything changes on the original it won't affect me.

I have forked [the repo](https://github.com/randomdude/gcc-cross-x86_64-elf) corresponding to that image to [my own repo](https://github.com/davidcallanan/gcc-cross-x86_64-elf).

I have cloned the repo and am trying to build it:

```
docker build . -t davcal/gcc-cross-x86_64-elf
```

I am getting this error:

```
+ cd /usr/local/src
+ ./build-binutils.sh 2.31.1
/bin/sh: 1: ./build-binutils.sh: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c set -x  && cd /usr/local/src    && ./build-binutils.sh ${BINUTILS_VERSION}      && ./build-gcc.sh ${GCC_VERSION}' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

[image]

What makes no sense to me is that if I use the original image, it builds successfully:

```
FROM randomdude/gcc-cross-x86_64-elf
...
```

Maybe Docker Hub stores a pre-built image?

How do I fix this?

Note: I am using Windows. This shouldn't make a difference since the error originates within the container.

**Edit**

I tried patching the `Dockerfile` to chmod executable permissions to the sh files in case that was causing problems on Windows. Unfortunately, the exact same error occurs.

```
RUN set -x \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/src/build-binutils.sh \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/src/build-gcc.sh \
    && cd /usr/local/src \
    && ./build-binutils.sh ${BINUTILS_VERSION} \
    && ./build-gcc.sh ${GCC_VERSION}
```

**Edit 2**

[Following this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26222636/1541397), I inspected the container to see if the sh files actually exist. Here is the output.

I ran `docker run --rm -it c53693f11514 bash`, including the hash of the intermediate container of the previous successful step of the `Dockerfile`.

This is the output showing that the files do exist:

```
root@9b8a64ac2090:/# cd usr/local/src
root@9b8a64ac2090:/usr/local/src# ls
binutils-2.31.1  build-binutils.sh  build-gcc.sh  gcc-8.2.0
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce on my Mac. I cloned the repo, `cd`ed into it, copy/paste/ran your `docker build` command, and it got to the `./build-binutils.sh 2.31.1` step without error.

Comment: @Hcaertnit Wow. Well thanks for testing that! At least I now know it's something wrong with my own machine.

Comment: `ADD` is just like `COPY` except it has a few nifty features like downloading URLs automatically and extracting tar archives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958548/16442705

Comment: Let me give it a shot on Windows.

Comment: @Hcaertnit I just realized, I removed that from the question :) It would be great if you cant test on windows, thanks

Comment: I would guess the issue may be exec bit missing on the script when cloning on windows. Try to add a `chmod +x /usr/local/src/build-binutils.sh` before the execution of the script.

Comment: @zigarn Interesting idea, but that didn't fix it. It seems that the file itself is not found, almost as if the previous `cd` command wasn't working.

Comment: What's funny is that when I [inspect the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220957/how-can-i-inspect-the-file-system-of-a-failed-docker-build), the files are there!

Comment: And what are the permissions on the file?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show how you did add the `chmod` and what is the output? Can you also add the procedure and result of your container inspection?

Comment: I'd guess you included windows linefeeds in your shell script. If so, you'll want to configure git to not break scripts like that with it's automatic linefeed translation.

Comment: @BMitch Interesting. I will check if that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the described symptoms, file exists, is a shell script, and works on other machines, the "file not found" error is most likely from Winidows linefeeds being added to the file. When the Linux kernel processes a shell script, it looks at the first line, the `#!/bin/sh` or similar, and then finds that interpreter to run the shell script. If that interpreter isn't found, you'll get a "file not found" error.

In this case, the file it's looking for won't be `/bin/sh`, but instead `/bin/sh\r` or `/bin/sh^M` depending on how you want to represent the carriage return character. You can fix that for single files with a tool like `dos2unix` but in general, you'll want to fix git itself since there are likely other files that have had their linefeeds corrupted. For details on adjusting the behavior of git, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf).